# Extend generic List

Tags: java, list

I am a C# programmer and have agreed to help a fried doing Java homework.

In one example I want to create a class that extends a generic List. In C# this looks like

```
public class MyListClass : List<MyCustomType>
```

I have tried

```
public class MyListClass extends List<MyCustomType>
```

and get the error "no interface expected here". Well, I am not trying to use an interface... Any hints?

Comment: `List` in Java is an interface. The equivalent in C# would be an `IList`. That is probably what's confusing you.

Comment: good point. I have used LinkedList now and so far it behaves as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend interface. You must implement it.
But you can extend one of implementations (LinkedList for example):

```
public class MyListClass extends LinkedList<MyCustomType> {
```

Comment: `You must to implement him` : interface is not a guy.

Comment: Sorry for my english. Russian "inteface" is masculine.

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.List` is a interface. You need to implement it not extend it.

```
public class MyListClass implements List<MyCustomType>{
}
```

Comment: If your class is concrete then you have to otherwise you can make your class abstract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That seems sounds not at all practical. There are roughly 30 methods that need to be implemented. Kinda not worth the effort if I just want to use the damn thing...

Comment: @Peter - then extend an `AbstractList`

Answer (score 1):

Java ain't C++, so forget all about standard templates.

What you probably want is just a *typed* List:

```
List<MyCustomType> myList = new ArrayList<MyCustomType>();
```

and that's all.

It would be unusual to have "extending a generic class" as a goal for an assignment. It is unusual in the real world too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a generic class / interface

```
public class MyListClass<T> implements List<T> { }
```

Or

```
public interface MyListInterface<T> extends List<T> { }
```

Or best of all

```
public class MyListClass<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> { }
```